# why we use join to get data from more one table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I use windows 7 and oracle 11g , so when we want to get data from more than one table we use join or we use normal selection :

```
select d.department_id,e.employee_id
from employees e,departments d
where d.department_id = e.employee_id;
```

my question is

> why we just use this simple way to get data from more than one table? why people use join or any another ways and ignore this way ??

im sorry for bad english

Comment: *"why we just use this simple way to get data from more than one table"* - Because some people are so adamant and unwilling to adopt  explicit **join** syntax inspite of it being in practice for a quarter-century!

Answer (score 1):

The query that you provided is written in SQL-89 join syntax. This is an old outdated syntax which is sometimes hard to read.

```
select d.department_id,e.employee_id
from employees e,departments d
where d.department_id = e.employee_id;
```

What if you have to join more than two tables? What if the join condition is not that simple?
You will just have lots of conditions in your `WHERE` clause which are hardly to be matched to the tables they're applied on.

Your query should be rewritten to:

```
select d.department_id,e.employee_id
from employees e 
   join departments d on d.department_id = e.employee_id;
```

Both queries are equal, but the latter uses SQL-92 join syntax which is preferrable. It's clear, obvious and easy to read.

If you're still in doubt, try writing a query joining more then 5 tables. And you will see the advantages of the new syntax.

Comment: Right; and try to outer-join the same table to two (or more) other tables (using the *old* syntax).

Comment: And don't forget about outer joins!  The old syntax is much less powerful.